# Loop over object and remove the keys based on next key value JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with key value pair, where value would be an array. Something like this

```
{
"a": [12],
"b": [1,3],
"c": [0,4],
"d": [0.5],
"e": [3,4],
"f": [3,4],
"g": [],
"h": [],
}
```

I want to loop over this object and keep on the last key with no empty array. So basically form the above example I just want to keep the **f** key since it is the last key without empty array and remove every other key except this one. And the object should look like this.

```
 {
    "f": [3,4]
 }
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Is it ok to use delete method?

Comment: How do you define "last key" - do you want the alphanumerically highest entry or whatever comes last in the natural order of the keys?

Comment: Whatever comes last in the natural order.

Comment: Your question doesn't include an attempt to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over the keys of the array. This will create an array that you can and should sort however you require, as there is no "natural order" for object properties in javascript.

```js
var obj = {
  "a": [12],
  "b": [1, 3],
  "c": [0, 4],
  "d": [0.5],
  "e": [3, 4],
  "f": [3, 4],
  "g": [],
  "h": [],
};

var newObj = {};
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();
for(var i=keys.length; i--;){
  if(obj[keys[i]].length){
    newObj[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: If there are more key-values after an empty element, it will still return the the first match

Comment: Fails for `obj = { b: [1], a: [2]}` - produces `b` instead of `a`. OP requires the highest natural order. Also fails for `obj = {a: [1], b: [], c: [3]}` - returns `a` instead of the last element with non-empty array which is `c`.

Comment: I assumed there wouldn't be more after the first empty. I've changed it to iterate backwards and return the first non-empty.

Comment: Now the `for` initialiser is incorrect - it skips every other element (the last index) since instead of `i >= 0` it has `i--` thus it starts the actual iteration at `keys.length -2`.

Comment: @VLAZ - no, that's not true. it starts i out as the array's length and subtracts one each time. try it. that is the correct way to iterate over an array backwards.

Comment: @VLAZ - you're still wrong. the loop exits at zero. negative numbers are truthy. if `i` ever somehow got to a negative number it would iterate infinitely. it is evaluating i before subtracting (i--, not --i) and since there is no such thing as an array with a negative number of items..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, I traversed it backwards for a non-empty array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
<script>
    var obj = {
        "a": [12],
        "b": [1, 3],
        "c": [0, 4],
        "d": [0.5],
        "e": [3, 4],
        "f": [3, 4],
        "g": [],
        "h": [],
    };

    const n = Object.keys(obj).length;
    const k = Object.keys(obj);

    for (let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (obj[k[i]].length != 0) {
            ans = {
                [k[i]]: obj[k[i]]
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(ans);
</script>
```